# Find all birthdays within the next 2 weeks

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to find all of the employees whose birthday is upcoming in the next 14 days.

I've tried using WHERE DATEDIFF(day, birthday_dt, CURRENT_DATE) <=14

```
SELECT
    full_name,
    birthday_dt,
FROM
    Employees
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(day, birthday_dt, CURRENT_DATE) <=14;
```

I expect the results to show as:

```
Walter White  |   08-29-1957
Mickey Mouse  |   09-01-1999
```

But I received empty results because no employee is 14 days old.

Comment: ...and? what showed instead? why was that wrong? why is the correct data correct? what is the full input data? etc.

Comment: No results returned because no employee is 14 days old. I want to find employees whose birthday anniversary is within 14 days of today.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    full_name,
    birthday_dt,
FROM
    Employees
WHERE
    365 - DATEDIFF(day, birthday_dt, current_date)%365 <= 14;
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the `365 -`, given that the 2nd part is returning the modulo? (I didn't try it, just thinking about it.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried the query without the `365 -` and that returned all birthdays 14 days prior and after current date. The `365 -` ensures that the results show only birthdays 14 days including and after current date, which is what I was looking for.